# PHP ActiveRecord with bridge tables

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

I'm trying to build the association between my "`homes`" table and "`furniture`" table.

Basically, a home can have multiple furniture, so I have a home_furniture_bridge table that looks like this:

```
home_id | furniture_id
```

Obviously, the relationship with home to home_furniture_bridge is irrelevant, it's the relationship between home and furniture that matters. How would this association be depicted in PHP ActiveRecord?

Edit: Currently I have a home.php model and a furniture.php model.  I wouldn't need a home_furniture_bridge model would I?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use this many-to-many association, you need to define the 3rd model and use the `has_many` `through` syntax in one of the models:

```
class Home extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $has_many = array(
            array('home_furniture_bridge', 'class_name' => 'HomeFurnitureBridge'),
            array('furniture', 'class_name' => 'Furniture', 'through' => 'home_furniture_bridge')
    );
}

class HomeFurnitureBridge extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $belongs_to = array(
            array('home'),
            array('furniture', 'class_name' => 'Furniture')
    );
}

class Furniture extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $has_many = array(
            array('homes')
    );
}
```

Note that you have to use class names for your `home_furniture_bridge` and `furniture`, since php AR works with plural/singular conventions for tables and class names.